# How to set margins when printing Xcode source code?

Tags: xcode, printing, margins

[screen print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6FtF.png)

I cannot determine how to set margins when printing Xcode source.  Xcode sets a good top margin but prints to the absolute bottom of the page.  The printer then drops the last line when printing.  One would think the presets in the Print popup would have a margin setting but I am missing it if it exists.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The printer I have the same problem on is a network connected Brother laser printer.

Comment: My printer is a HP2600n and is a network connected printer as well.  Interesting.  I may try a direct USB print as a test.